# Adding a .dll from GAC to SSIS script component doesn't work

Tags: ssis, gac, class-library, gacutil, script-component

I am trying to reference a custom class library (C#) in a script component of my SSIS package. The library **has a strong name**. I deployed the .dll to **GAC via gacutil**. I am administrator and I really tried everything else I could find on the www. If I try to reference from any local folder it does work fine. But referencing it from GAC does simply not work. In the following screenshot I simply went to my **script component** -> **References** -> **Add Reference**. Here I navigated to "C:\Windows\assembly":

[image]

My libraries can be found there but I am not able to add anything. Not even the files that were already there.

What am I doing wrong?

Btw I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008"

Comment: remove them from GAC reboot add them to GAC reboot. try again.  it can be a pain.  oh and do a full search of your hard drive make sure there isn't a version of the DLLs hanging out anywhere else.

Comment: @DaImTo are you sure? Like I mentioned before I am not able to add any reference not only the custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that referencing .dll's from GAC can be a little tricky with VS 2008. This is how I solved it.

I simply put my dll in a arbitrary local folder and refrenced it in my script component. I also installed the very same library in the gac via gacutil.exe

Now I simply deleted the file from the arbitrary local folder mentioned above. What happened was that VS automatically tried to find this file in gac. So it was referenced automatically from gac.